# движение 2d персонажа в воде

Tags: unity3d

Как можно сделать так, что бы игрок смотрел вверх когда плывет вверх, что бы смотрел по диагонали когда плывет по диагонали. То есть смотрел туда куда плывет. Заранее спасибо.
[image]

Comment: Очевидно, поворачивать игрока в направлении вектора скорости. Это скорее всего нужно делать там, где вы двигаете его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам подойдет вот такое простое вращение:

```
public class Player {
    [SerializeField] private float Speed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 InputVec = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        rb.AddForce(InputVec * Speed, ForceMode2D.Force);

        transform.up = rb.velocity.normalized; // Вот в этой строке заключается вращение
    }
}
```

Немного более дерганным, но резким, будет вращение такой строкой:

```
transform.up = InputVec.normalized;
```

Показываю в 2D, потому что у вас именно 2D.

Comment: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ

Comment: @qqqqvesd Если мой ответ вам помог, пожалуйста, нажмите галочку слева, чтобы показать это

Comment: можно еще мини вопрос. Что означает  normolized в rb.velocity.normalized

Comment: normalized - это нормализация вектора, то есть приведение его к длине единицы. Растягивание или сжатие, но после этого его длина = 1. Можете проверить выводом `rb.velocity.normalized.magnitude`. `magnitude` - показывает длину вектора: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50212009/vector3-magnitude-and-vector3-normalized-explanation

Comment: ну я чет все равно не понял как работает эта строчка. Моджете пожалуйста объяснить

Comment: rb.velocity - это вектор скорости (векторы проходят в 9 классе. Для корректного вращения вектор должен быть длинной ЕДИНИЦА. Это свойство `normalized` сохраняет направление вектора, но длину его ставит в ЕДИНИЦУ. То есть после применения normalized длина вектора = 1